# How to do a self outer join in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, outer-join, self-join

How can one do a self outer join in oracle ? (I'm using 11g)

I tried the following query with lots of combinations of (+) everywhere and left/right :

```
select t1.name, t1.status, t2.status
from my_tab t1 outer join my_tab t2
on t1.name = t2.name
where t1.year= X and t2.year = Y and t1.status <> t2.status;
```

expected result : people who changed status between year X and Y, as well as new people and people who disappeared

got only people who changed status

---

Oracle's [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries006.htm) says that

> You cannot use the (+) operator to outer-join a table to itself

Does it apply only to the (+) operator, or should I read "you cannot outer join a table to itself" ?

Comment: AFAIK, that limitation only applies to the `(+)` operator (another good reason not to use it anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Dirty solution :

```
--request presented above
select t1.name, t1.status as status_X, t2.status as status_Y
from my_tab t1 join my_tab t2
on t1.name = t2.name
where t1.year = X and t2.year = Y and t1.status <> t2.status

union
--stuff that disappeared from X to Y
select name, status, null
from my_tab
where year = X and name not in (select name from my_tab where year = Y)

union
--new stuff
select name, null, status
from my_tab
where year = Y and name not in (select name from my_tab where year = X)
```